# geotiff can't plotty with leaflet

Tags: web, gis, tiff, geo, geotiff

```js
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([12.613507, 101.929989], 6);
L.tileLayer(
  'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw',
  {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                 '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                 'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
  }
).addTo(map); 
    
var MSL = L.leafletGeotiff(
  url = 'tif/big.tif',
  options = {
    band: 0,
    displayMin: -0.25,
    displayMax: 0.25,
    name: 'MSL',
    colorScale: 'rainbow'
  }
).addTo(mymap);
```

I don't know why `url = 'tif/big.tif'` is not show on my map. Can anyone help me in the direction how to resolve this please?
[This is my image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1suYS.png)

Note: I run this file locally and not on a server

Comment: This is not a tiff file but a png image

Comment: I do want to ask which leafletGeotiff plugin are u using? Cause there are many and the leaflet-geotiff plugin that is available on npmjs hasn't been updated for 3 years. You should be able to use the file attribute instead of the url attribute for local files instead of an external url and in the most recent version of leaflet-geotiff-2 you can even use fromBlob and fromArrayBuffer as sourceFunction like  GeoTiff.fromArrayBuffer and then url can be left empty and arrayBuffer should then contain the buffered source of the source tiff to be loaded. https://github.com/danwild/leaflet-geotiff-2

Answer (score 0):

This can be two issues and one of them is very easy, change **addTo(mymap)** to **addTo(map)**.

Secondly you need to make sure that your tiff is a EPSG:4326 tiff which are the only tiff files that are supported.

As last I suggest to always use full static or relative path so instead of **'tif/big.tif** use **./tif/big.tif** and even better is to use the **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** and other path related built-in variables which will make sure that on both Linux and Windows the correct **/** or **\** is used and also the correct root path is used for your project source code.